# How to create a npm project generator without Yeoman

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, scaffolding

I want to create a project generator (scaffolding) tool with npm but don't want to use Yeoman, something like the create-react-app or Angular cli where I can just run a command and the folders and files are loaded.

I don't need step by step just want to know if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create js script which creates a folder structure for you.
We created something similar, which could create a folder structure using a `json` for defining the structure. Its called [all-doer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-doer)

It basically uses the `fs` module to create files and directories.

Furthermore the [npm tutorial](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) would help around how to get this published

Comment: i think that was the direction i was looking for. thanks

Comment: You can mark it as answered. So it solves the problem for anyone else who stumbles here

Comment: It's already been done here: http://bssdev.biz/DevTools/React-Turbo-Scaffolding-Free-Download   I wouldn't bother reinventing the wheel.